# How to make the bootstrap button,when clicked to redirect to a specific page

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller

Here is the code i have

```
<div class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block for-get-button">
  <%= link_to "Get this box for", download_picture_path(@gig), :target => "_blank" %> <%= @gig.pointsneeded %> points
</div>
```

To clarify the first code above,redirects the user where i need.

```
<%= link_to "Get this box for", download_picture_path(@gig), :target => "_blank" %>
```

The second code,just shows the number of points required

```
<%= @gig.pointsneeded %>
```

and the word "**points**" is just a word that comes after the code.

and this is the css for all the code:

```
.btn.btn-default.btn-lg.btn-block.for-get-button {
  background-color: #000000;
  text-color: #00FFFF;
  a:link { 
    color: #00FFFF;
  }
  a:visited { 
    color: #00FFFF;
  }
  a:hover { 
    color: #00FFFF;
  }
  a:active { 
    color: #00FFFF;
  }
  color: #00FFFF;
}
```

> **Question:** how to make this whole code when clicked on any part/side of the button that is formed around it,when clicked it
>   should redirect to download_picture_path(@gig).Because now,on hover over the **"Get this box for"** an underline appears,and i have to click EXACTLY on **"Get this box for"** to get redirected where i need,when i should be able to click anywhere in the button to get redirected.

hope I made myself clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
<%= link_to "Get this box for #{@gig.pointsneeded} points", download_picture_path(@gig), :target => "_blank", class: "btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block for-get-button" %>
```

Although my code might not on the styling since i took out the div and placed it on the link_to. but it should solve the problem